# postgres 'psql' command is not recognized in windows environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

It seems like I have it set up, I have my database.yml using postgres, and I can connect the database with pgadmin III, but when I tried using the psql command to test what version, it says that is is not recognized? Any idea what I should be doing?

I'm using windows and using command prompt with Ruby on Rails. Using PostgreSQL 9.2 installed with the EnterpriseDB one-click installer.

Comment: Pg version? What installer did you use?Windows version?

Comment: @CraigRinger It was the enterprise version, with 9.2 per your answer below, but it seems like it still doesn't work when I added psql.exe in my path

Comment: "Enterprise"? Do you mean the EnterpriseDB version?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes. I did the windows one-click installer package

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming you installed PostgreSQL on Windows with the PostgreSQL "One-click" installer packaged by EnterpriseDB, `psql` is not added to the `PATH` automatically. That's partly because adding it to the path could otherwise cause confusion when people have multiple versions of PostgreSQL installed.

You need to specify the full explicit path to `psql`, eg:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Postgresql\9.2\bin\psql.exe"
```

or add `psql` to the user `PATH` environment variable, see eg [this guide](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#0).

Comment: Do I need to restart my command prompt? I have these in my path: `C:\PostgresSQL\9.2\;C:\PostgresSQL\9.2\bin;C:\PostgresSQL\9.2\bin\psql.exe`. I closed the prompt and opened it again but when I tried typing `psql` its still not recognized?

Comment: I put it on my systems environment

Comment: @andrewliu Only the middle one actually makes sense; you don't set the path directly to the executable, nor to some arbitrary parent directory, the path must contain the immediate parent directory. You should generally modify the user path not the system path; if no `PATH` variable exists for the user then add one. To verify that it's correct close and reopen `cmd.exe` and then type `echo "%PATH%"`. Edit your question to add the result (copy and paste it).

Comment: @andrewliu Did you install PostgreSQL to `C:\PostgreSQL` ? That's an unusual and non-default install location. Are you sure it isn't in `Program Files` like usual.

Comment: I installed it into `C:\PostgresSQL` because there was an issue before and I read somewhere that it needs to be installed outside of `Program Files` for my application to work or something... But as long as my PATH is to the corrected .exe file, it shouldn't be a problem where I install it right?

Comment: @andrewliu No, your `PATH` must be to *the folder containing `psql.exe`*, not to `psql.exe` its self. What if you run the command with absolute path, eg (assuming your install has `PostgreSQL` mis-spelled as `PostgresSQL` like your comments) `"C:\PostgresSQL\9.2\bin\psql.exe"`. The quotes are required. Have you actually checked the path? Is there a `9.2` intermediate path in your install?

Comment: I have checked the path, and it is 9.2, and the path is correct, I copied straight from the folder path itself, and I added quotes, but it still doesn't work. This is a head scratcher...

Comment: Okay, I think adding it to the user instead of system path works... now its saying that my role name doesn't exists... its better than saying its not referenced

Comment: @andrewliu Sounds like you might've missed a semicolon when appending to the system path or something. Glad it's working. The new error is completely normal; you need to specify a username to log in. Read [the user manual on client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html). If you're still stuck *after* reading the manual post a new question.

Answer (score 14):

Open Command Line

```
psql --version
```

if on above line psql version is not displayed, then follow below steps

```
(For Windows 7 OS)

Mycomputer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->EnvironmentVariables->Path->Edit->
(Donot remove any existing Path)
```

Add this

```
;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib
```

save it then

Reopen Command Prompt and repeat

```
psql --version

C:\Users\rumi>psql --version

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
```

Comment: works on Windows 10 also! Though I couldn't install pg into "c:\program files".

Comment: Is is not lib, it should be `bin`

Answer (score 3):

it is because there should not be space between the `;` and your psql path so it should be like `*****;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\`.

If there is a space after `******`; then it will not work. You can actually type `%PATH%`in your cmd prompt and see how your environment variable and space looks like. I tried both cases for you, the first with space had the same error you mentioned and the second without space worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set both the bin AND the lib path in your PATH environment variable separated by semicolons:

%PROGRAMFILES%\Postgresql\9.2\bin;%PROGRAMFILES%\Postgresql\9.2\lib

Comment: Also don't forget to re-open CMD.